# Add event to Google Calendar via API v3 using OAuth 2.0 service account?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am getting a forbidden (403) when trying to add an event to my calendar (API v3 & OAuth2), as follows:

```
var service = CalendarService();
CalendarListResource.ListRequest request = service.CalendarList.List();
IList<CalendarListEntry> calendarList = request.Execute().Items;
foreach (CalendarListEntry entry in calendarList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Summary:{0}\nLocation:{1}\nTimeZone:{2}",
        entry.Summary, entry.Location, entry.TimeZone
        );
}

var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
var eventBody = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event
{
    Description = "Test 4 description",
    Summary = "Test 4 summary",
    Start = new EventDateTime
    {
        DateTime = startDate
    },
    End = new EventDateTime
    {
        DateTime = endDate
    }
};
var insertRequest = service.Events.Insert(calendarId: calendarId_emailAddress, body: eventBody); //InsertRequest
insertRequest.Execute();
```

I have set up oauth2 service account, granted scopes, and shared the calendar.  However, something I noticed on the calendar share part is that I am unable (no option available) to share for read/write.  Only option is "freeBusyRead".

EDIT:

Let me add that calendarId_emailAddress = "my_email_address".  I was able to add an event.  No errors.  And then iterate and find it.  But it does not show up in my calendar.  I seem to not be making the connection between the calendarId and the "actual calendar" in my user panel.

So how to do this.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Google Apps domain probably limits the level of sharing to external accounts to free/busy only. Service accounts, even when created by a domain user, are always considered external to the domain.

The proper way to do this would be to authorize the service account to act on behalf of your domain users and then, authenticating as the service account and acting on behalf of the user, add the event to the user calendar. [Domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) is discussed in the Drive API docs but can easily be applied to Calendar API also.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks Jay.  Yes, as mentioned in my post above, I have "granted scopes".  To expand on that I have gone through that link you provided and granted account xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com, the scopes:

Groups Provisioning  https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/
Contacts (Read/Write)  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
Calendar (Read-Write)  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly

Comment: **** Let me add that calendarId_emailAddress = "my_email_address".  I was able to add an event.  No errors.  And then iterate and find it.  But it does not show up in my calendar.  I seem to not be making the connection between the calendarId and the "actual calendar" in my user panel.

Comment: upvoted your input because it did have me taking a closer look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was in the authentication of the service.  Scenarios...

1)  ServiceAccountCredential with no user set, and calendarId = "primary" yields an entry into calendar.  Which calendar?  Who knows.  I can't see the entry in my interface of that user, but I do find the entry in the Events.List("primary")

2)  ServiceAccountCredential with user set to email of target calendar, and calendarId = "primary" yields an entry into calendar, which I do see in my interface of that user, and also find the entry in the Events.List("primary")

Scenario #1 really baffles me.  No idea how to see that event in the calendar.

Any insight into this would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're not specifying a user account when doing OAuth authentication, your accessing the service account's calendar.